# Characteristic function on open set is upper-semicontinous

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the the open set $A \subset X$ and define on it the characteristic function $$\mathbb{1}_A(x)={ \begin{cases}
1, x \in A\\
\infty, x \not \in A
\end{cases}}$$
Then, the characteristic function $\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ is upper-semicontinous for $x \in A$, as noted in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity, i.e. $$lim \sup_{k \to \infty} \mathbb{1} (x_k) \leq \mathbb{1} (x),$$

for some sequence $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$  with limit $x \in A$ or put differently:

$\mathbb{1}_A(x)$ is upper-semicontinous iff for every real $y > \mathbb{1}_A(x)$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $y > \mathbb{1}_A(x)$ for all $x_k \in U$.

Conversely for closed sets. Why are those two definitions equivalent in the case of the characteristic function and in general?

Comment: it's a classic argument by contradiction, try by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down. We have two things we want to show are equivalent. Fix $A$ and let $\chi_A$ be the characteristic function for $A$.

1. For any sequence $(x_k) \subseteq X$ with $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} x_k = x \in A$, we have
   $$\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \chi_A (x_k) \leq \chi_A(x).$$
2. For every real $y > \chi_A(x)$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ so that $y > \chi_A(x_k)$ for every $x_k \in U$.

Let's show $1) \implies 2)$. Let $y > \chi_A(x)$. Per your definition, this can only happen if $x \in A$. Suppose that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ we can find $x_k \in U$ so that $y \leq \chi_A(x_k)$. Then by 1) we see that
$$y \leq \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \chi_A(x_k) \leq \chi_A(x),$$
a contradiction.

Let's show $2) \implies 1)$. Suppose we have a sequence $x_k \rightarrow x \in A$ such that $\limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \chi_A(x_k) > \chi_A(x)$. Let $y := \limsup_{k \rightarrow \infty} \chi_A(x_k)$. Then by 2), we see that we can find a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ so that $y > \chi_A(x_k)$ for every $x_k \in U$. Since $x_k \rightarrow x$, we have that $x_k$ is in $U$ for sufficiently large $k$, but this is a contradiction to our limsup assumption.